# Connection Error stockPortfolio::getReturns

Tags: r

I'm running a portfolio optimization and to do that I want to download historical stock data using the stockPortfolio package. I ran the below code, which should generate the pricing data from Yahoo Finance. Instead, I'm getting an error:

````
```{r}
stocks <- c("AAPL")
getReturns(ticker = stocks, freq = "year")
```
````

Here's the traceback:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
4.file(file, "rt")
3.read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
2.read.delim(URL, TRUE, sep = ",")
1.getReturns(ticker = stocks, freq = "year")
```

Looking around other threads, I can't find a great answer. I have the [latest version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534077/r-stockportfolio-package-not-connecting-to-yahoo) and [updating my proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467277/proxy-setting-for-r) doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getReturns` doesn't work anymore because Yahoo Finance has discontinued the service on which most functions fetching data from Yahoo rely (similar problems for `get.hist.quote` from `tseries` or `getSymbols` from `quantmod`). I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221631/r-getreturns-yahoo-finance-api?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the same issue.

Instead, you can just download the data from Yahoo manually and import it with `read.csv`. Alternatively, you could get the (daily) data from google with `getSymbols`:

```
    library(quantmod)
    S <- getSymbols("AAPL", src = 'google', auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2004-01-01", to = "2016-12-31")
```